# Why is my calculated column using CASE returning an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, calculated-columns

I am using SQL Server and SSMS. I have a table called 'Correspondence'. It contains a column called 'Type'. I have created an empty column called 'TypeCode'. I'm trying to insert numerical values based on values in the 'Type column'. Here is my code so far:

```
INSERT INTO Correspondence (TypeCode)
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN [Type] = 'letter' THEN 1
            WHEN [Type] = 'email' THEN 2
            WHEN [Type] = 'User Note' THEN 3
            ELSE 4
        END;
```

When I execute the code I get the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The multi-part identifier "Correspondence.Type" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid column name 'Type'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid column name 'Type'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since there's no `FROM` clause in your `SELECT` maybe ?!?!?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to UPDATE the value in the column - if so, then you need to use UPDATE instead of trying to insert a new row.

Comment: I had created an empty column with entirely empty rows at the time. When I tried INSERT it just wouldn't work for some reason. Some variants inserted values but they would be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need an `UPDATE` statement (not `INSERT` which would add new rows in the table):

```
UPDATE Correspondence 
SET TypeCode = CASE [Type]
                 WHEN 'letter' THEN 1
                 WHEN 'email' THEN 2
                 WHEN 'User Note' THEN 3
                 ELSE 4
               END;
```

But, you could create the new column as a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) (virtual or persisted) so that you would not need to update anything:

```
ALTER TABLE Correspondence ADD TypeCode AS 
CASE [Type]
  WHEN 'letter' THEN 1
  WHEN 'email' THEN 2
  WHEN 'User Note' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7970e5f5c92893e4f2b0dbb5e7e0eaab).

Comment: Is update needed for specific functions only like CASE?. For instance when using: 
INSERT INTO TicketResponse (TicketNumber, ResponseDate,ActionTaken)
SELECT [Ticket #], [Response On],[Action Taken] update is not needed.
FROM Correspondence;

Comment: @rapha123 when you add a new column (without a default value) to a table that is already populated, the new column has nulls in every row. In this case you must update the table, meaning you want to change the values for this column. You should use INSERT when you want to add new rows in a table.